# Publish Maven artifacts on FTP with Hudson FTP Publisher Plugin

Tags: ftp, hudson

I'm building a number of artefacts (zip files for different environments: test, dev) using the maven-assembly-plugin using a specialized Maven profile. These artefacts I want to copy/collect on on a FTP server keeping the version (01.07.10.16.Wed-1626) as a folder, so I need to copy from **test/build/01.07.10.16.Wed-1626/** to **ftp://my-ftp-server:21/projects/myserver-1.7/01.07.10.16.Wed-1626/**

The layout for the Maven output is this:

```
target/
  build/
    01.07.10.16.Wed-1626/
      my-server-01.07.10.16.Wed-1626-dev.zip 
      my-server-01.07.10.16.Wed-1626-test.zip
```

For copying the artefacts I'm using [FTP Publisher Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/FTP-Publisher+Plugin) but it seams I miss something since that even the build is OK and the artefacts are build without problem but the job is finishing without copying the artefacts, and in the console there is no log info about copying the artefacts

My FTP publisher config (**FTP repository hosts**) is:

```
Hostname: my-ftp-server
Port: 21
Timeout: 10000
Root Repository Path: projects
User Name: my-user
Password: my-pass
```

My Hudson job FTP publisher config (**Publish artifacts to FTP**) is:

```
FTP site: my-ftp-server
Files to upload
    Source: target/build/**
    Destination: myserver-1.7
```

Additional issues:
**1:** There is any log (hou can the FTP Uploader log can be enabled) to check if there are any FTP copy errors ?
**2:** There is any problem with the file pattern (source) or with the dest ?
**3:** I can also use **maven-antrun-plugin** for upload but since this post-buil task should be used just by Hudson, should be defined outside of the POM.

Comment: BTW, you can deploy these artifacts with Maven itself. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

Comment: As mentioned, I need to upload some "non-attached" zips, generated using the maven-assembly-plugin and still need to keep the actual artifact (my-server-1.7.jar) uploaded on an actual Maven repository (Nexus) so I'll not mix them

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Hudson's Artifactory Plugin ? http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Artifactory+Plugin